# Integration Test not reading from App.Config file

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

I am working on a console application that at the moment is only reading from one table from my database. I have a connection string in my app.config that connects to my database and is passed into my class that is getting data from my table. The code for the class is below:

```
public class DatabaseReader
{
        private readonly string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;

        public List<Admin> GetAllAdmins()
        {
            var adminDatabaseReader = new AdminDatabaseReader(_connectionString);
            return adminDatabaseReader.GetAll();
        }
}
```

And then here is my app.config file for my non-test project that this is calling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Database" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And then here is my current unit test:

```
[TestClass]
    public class AdminDatabaseReaderTests
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;

        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("Database Tests")]
        public void AdminDatabaseReader_GetAll_WhenCallingDatabase_ShouldReturnListOfAdminTableRows()
        {
            // Arrange
            var adminDatabaseReader = new AdminDatabaseReader(_connectionString);

            // Act
            var listOfAdmins = adminDatabaseReader.GetAll();

            // Assert
        }
    }
```

Here is the test project app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Database" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The issue that I am running into is that when I run my application, it gets the database from the connection string in my app.config in my non testing project and gets the data no problem. However, when I try to run my test from above, my connection string comes back as null. Does anyone know why this happens? Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have double checked for spelling mistakes in my app.config in my testing project and there are none.

I am working in Visual Studio 2019 with C# 9 and .NET 5. This test is also in the MSTests framework.

Comment: Please share testing project's app.config

Comment: @opel Test Project app.config has been added

Comment: It's a long shot, but check for hidden characters inside attribute "connectionString" in test project's app.config. Regardless, try isolating issue by calling ConfigurationManager from indide your test.

Comment: @opel there are no hidden characters and I also moved the ConfigurationManager connection string into my test method and I end up getting the same thing.